# Use a privacy-friendly reCaptcha alternative

Tags: discussion, captcha, privacy

I'm very concerned with Google tracking my online activity. According to [this article](https://www.fastcompany.com/90369697/googles-new-recaptcha-has-a-dark-side), Google's reCaptcha v3 poses significant privacy concerns, including:

- sending "hardware and software information, including device and application data, back to Google for analysis"
- unclear usage of the collected data, as Google would "not clarify what it does with the data it captures about user behavior via reCaptcha, only that it is used for improving reCaptcha and general security purposes"
- encouraging website owners to embed reCaptcha code on all pages for greater accuracy, making tracking site-wide
- disadvantaging users without the Google cookie, as the algorithm uses Google's cookie to determine its risk score

**I'd really appreciate it if StackOverflow switched to a privacy-friendly captcha provider**, such as hCaptcha or a FOSS alternative.

---

There are other posts on here about replacing reCaptcha. However, they present very different reasons for replacing it, including:

- [usability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve) [problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143229/recaptcha-trying-to-find-out-how-far-it-can-go)
- [lack of reliability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229852/replacing-recaptcha)
- [crowdsourcing for a proprietary project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47047/please-give-me-a-choice-not-to-use-googles-recaptcha)

I haven't found one discussing privacy concerns, which is why I believe this post is not a duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on SE making changes because of privacy concerns that arise from tracking. Look for example at [Is SE allowing ads to use fingerprinting to track users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332974/352819) and [Embedding Facebook avatars enables tracking of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384864/7443472)

Comment: @Secespitus And yet, I'm holding out hope that SE will do the right thing. Especially when the competing hCaptcha presents no loss to them nor their users.